# Цикл не работает

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня цикл не выдает pass==1 как "true", хотя в файле есть необходимая последовательность.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace всмка
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            int pass=0;
            
            char l1 = 'М';
            int l1d=0;
            char l2 = 'о';
            int l2d=0;
            char l3 = 'л';
            int l3d=0;
            char l4 = 'о';
            int l4d=0;
            int re =0;
            
            char l5 = 'д';
            int l5d=0;
            char l6 = 'е';
            int l6d=0;
            char l7 = 'ц';
            int l7d=0;
            string b ="я ь";
            char l8 = 'ь';
            int l8d=0;
            
            string path = @"C:\MyTest1.txt";
            string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
            int a = text.Length-1;
            
                for(i=a; i>0; i--)
                {
                    if (text[i]==l8)
                    {if (text[i-1]==l7)
                        {if (text[i-3]==l6)
                            {if (text[i-4]==l5)
                                {if (text[i-5]==l4)
                                    {if (text[i-6]==l3)
                                        {if (text[i-7]==l2)
                                            {if (text[i-8]==l1)
                                                    pass=1; }}}}}}}
                }
            if(pass==1)
            {Console.WriteLine("Хід");}
        
         Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Сейчас лопнут глаза.*

```
            {if (text[i-1]==l7)
                {if (text[i-3]==l6)
```

А где `i-2`?